# Cookie vs jsessionid url token precedence

Tags: java, session, tomcat, cookies, jsessionid

how is it with `Set-Cookie: VS jsessionid url token`  precedence ?

Apache Tomcat just seem to ignore the token if cookie is set. Isn't it a little inconvenient behavior ? Or is it like this because of security reasons ?

this is the url of the request in servlet

```
....someParam=addFile;jsessionid=7A6ECCF009D4855821BCB45E0B744A7B'
```

and ID of the resulting Session corresponds to the cookie request header param...

This means, that it screws up handling of the request. For instance Spring-mvc resolves
`someParam` value to `addFile;jsessionid=7A6ECCF009D4855821BCB45E0B744A7B'` and it crashes with exception...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Servlet 2.4 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr154/index.html), URL re-writing is the lowest denomination of session tracking so I'm not surprised that `jsessionid` in the URL is ignored for clients who are accepting cookies. Read the section 7.1 for relevant details (i.e. session tracking).

As far as your updated question is concerned (Spring MVC related), there are a lot of articles/techniques out there which mention how to do away with the excessive baggage of `;jsessionid` in your URL by stripping them off using a filter or by using mod_rewrite. Do a google search for "jsessionid in url" and read through the links which follow.

Comment: The issue here, is that Tomcat should remove it if it accepts the cookie, because it remains in the url otherwise

Comment: There is nothing in the specification which states that `jsessionid` in the URL should be removed if the client accepts cookies. I'm not sure why your client URL contains a `jsessionid` if the client is accepting cookies? Are you putting in the `jsessionid` manually? Also, see my updated answer.

Comment: The reason is damn Flash technology http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1044 ... 3 years old bug and 77 votes and adobe just watching how people are hopelessly fighting it

Comment: Btw if it is in servlet spec. doesn't mean that servlet containers like Tomcat or Jetty have it implemented like this.

Comment: @lisak: To get around the flash bug, look into the url re-writing suggestion presented in my post. Basically, you should be good to go if you can manage to change the URL from `some=addFile;jsessionid` to `some=addFile&;jsessionid` (notice the `&`).

Comment: Also, AFAIK, Tomcat servlet container complies with the servlet specification and hence it *has* to implement the specification.

Comment: @Sanjay T. Sharma,  and what would I do with jsessionid ? I need tomcat to load the corresponding Session object.  I don't need sessionID in my controller, what would I do with it...it's useless

Comment: For example PHP engine listens to Cookie, PHPSESSIONID url token  !and!  phpsessionID POST request parameter. And it loads the corresponding Session Object... But Servlet containers don't, they only listen to Cookie and jsessionid url token... not http request parameters

Comment: Maybe I could create a Filter, that could do that, but I don't know how, or if it is even possible to load Session objects in Filter if you posses the Session ID ... I think that it is being done somewhere in Catalina processing before Filters can handle the request.

Comment: @lisak: My suggestion was in reply to your original question of Spring MVC crashing with exception. Regarding session, it is pretty obvious here that there is no simple solution to this issue. You can use some kind of header manipulator plugin for your load balancer which when sees a `jsessionid` in your URL creates an equivalent cookie. A bit hacky but worth a try in case you don't have any other ideas left.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, do let us know or update your question in case you get this thing working. This is an interesting problem.